# Format a registration key on entering

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to format a key while the user enters it into an input field.

The format of the code is like this `SF8S-48WD-IR78` (basically 4 alphanumeric chars divided by dashes).

The input should only accept typed alphanumeric chars and no dashes but put the dashes automatically at positions 5 and 10. The point is to eliminate human errors on typing or copying these codes in.

My code here works, but users keep entering extra dashes and I can't quite figure out how to prevent entering dashes without deleting them all together from the string.

```html
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('input#code').bind('input propertychange', function(){
                var val = $(this).val().toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9\-]/g, '');
                if(val.length > 4 && val[4] != '-') {
                    val = val.substring(0, 4) + '-' + val.substring(4);
                }
                if(val.length > 9 && val[9] != '-') {
                    val = val.substring(0, 9) + '-' + val.substring(9);
                } 
                if(val.length > 14) {
                    val = val.substr(0, 14);
                }
                $(this).val(val);
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `keydown` instead. This way you can prevent the event if it's a character you do not want in your field.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#code').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.key === "-") {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    var val = $(this).val().toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9\-]/g, '');
    if (val.length > 4 && val[4] != '-') {
      val = val.substring(0, 4) + '-' + val.substring(4);
    }
    if (val.length > 9 && val[9] != '-') {
      val = val.substring(0, 9) + '-' + val.substring(9);
    }
    if (val.length > 14) {
      val = val.substr(0, 14);
    }
    $(this).val(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Code: <input type="text" id="code" />
```

See More: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-keycode-list-keypress-event-key-codes/